# How to get a Empty http body using Unauthorized() in WebApi Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a function in a webapi Core controller that returns an IActionResult. When I return Unauthorized(), get a http response message that includes contents in the body.

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/problem+json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:bd2aaf31-7b2f-4d8e-b627-a27764a46523
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 24 Mar 2021 02:14:55 GMT

a2
{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7235#section-3.1","title":"Unauthorized","status":401,"traceId":"00-9d1f5fdb87116241a432f64d76ed8c35-8714a7bfa634c94f-00"}
0
```

How can I get it just to return a empty body like below as the web hook mechanism will error the messages if the body contains any value.

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:bd2aaf31-7b2f-4d8e-b627-a27764a46523
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 24 Mar 2021 02:14:55 GMT

0
```

The code looks like

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public classTestController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost("webhook")]
        public IActionResult Post()
        {

            if (<some test>))
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }
            
            // do something
            return Ok();
        }
     }
```

Comment: The `[.net]` tag is for .NET Framework, so I assume you mean `[.net-core]`. The `[core]` tag states: _"Use this tag to refer to processor cores or questions related to threads and parallel processing."_, which is unrelated to your question. Please ensure you read tag descriptions before using them, so that you don't misuse them (and potentially introduce misleading or conflicting details into your question by doing so).

Comment: Only add parameter in `return Unauthorized(" ")`, it will has no http body. But what is the purpose of this?

Comment: The Xero webhook "intent to receive" function, sends good and bad requests and a requirement is that the body is empty. https://developer.xero.com/documentation/webhooks/configuring-your-server#intent